# How to add header and footer on itext pdf page

Tags: java

I want to add Header and page number in itext pdf page when creating multiple copy of existing pdf.
Code example

```
       Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4,30,30,40,40);
        PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document,new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(path));
        while (i<=numberOfCopy ) {
            for(int page = 1; page <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); page++) {
                PdfImportedPage importedPage = writer.getImportedPage(reader, page);
                writer.addPage(importedPage);
                document.setPageCount(page);
            }   
            i++;
        }

            document.close();
            reader.close();
```